# Testing Saga using Jest that have other module dependencies

Tags: jestjs, saga

I am trying to test a saga that internally refers to an object with `RNFiresbase` dependency.

Below are my files, the `AccountSaga` imports `AccountRepo` which has a dependency on `RNFirebase` and when I test the 'Sign' saga from `AccountSaga` I get the below error. The test fails at initialization itself when the `AccountSaga` is imported in my test.

What is the right way to test my 'SignIn' Saga ?

```
 1 | import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
      2 | import { ACCOUNT_PATH } from './constants';
      3 | 
      4 | const ACCOUNT_REF = firebase.firestore().collection(ACCOUNT_PATH);
      Error: RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS, ensure you have correctly included the RNFirebase pod in your projects `Podfile` and have run `pod install`.
```

AccountRepo.js

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import { ACCOUNT_PATH } from './constants';

const ACCOUNT_REF = firebase.firestore().collection(ACCOUNT_PATH);

const AccountRepo = {

  getAccount(user){
    console.log('Getting account for user :'+user.uid);
    return ACCOUNT_REF.doc(user.uid).get().then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        return doc.data();
      } else {
        console.warn("No such document!");
        return null;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

AccountSaga.js

```
import { call, put, select , take, takeEvery} from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_UP,SHOW_SIGN_UP, SIGNED_IN, ERROR } from '../action/types';
import { AccountRepo } from '../repo';


  function *signIn(action) {
    try{
      const {user} = action.payload;
      console.log('In *SIGN_IN saga for user '+JSON.stringify(user));
      const account = yield call(AccountRepo.getAccount, user);
      console.log('account is '+account);
      if(account) {
        yield put({type: SIGNED_IN, payload:account});
      } else {
        yield put({type: SHOW_SIGN_UP, payload:user});
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error retrieving account '+error);
      yield put({type: ERROR,error});
    }
  }

export const AccountSagas = [
  takeEvery(SIGN_IN, signIn)
]
```

AccountSaga.test.js

```
import {signIn} from '../../app/saga/AccountSagas';
import { SIGN_IN, SIGN_UP,SHOW_SIGN_UP, SIGNED_IN, ERROR } from '../../app/action/types';
import { AccountRepo } from '../../app/repo';

describe(' >>> signIn', () => {

  const action = {type: SIGN_IN, payload: {user: {uid:'DFDDGDG'}}};
  const generator = signIn(action);
  it('+++ must call AccountRepo.getAccount', () => {
       //const generator = testFunction1("Gethyl")
       const testValue = generator.next().value;
       console.log(testValue);
       expect(testValue).toEqual(call(AccountRepo.getAccount,action.payload.user))
    });

} )
```